# Regular expression for matching text after a tag

Tags: php, regex

I have been unable to make a regular expression for matching text **outside** of brackets.

All examples I see are inside.

Consider the following strings:

```
<@231312312312> foobar foobar
<@231312312312> foobar <asad> foobar
<@231312312312> foobar foobar <asdasd>
```

I want the text that comes after the first <> tag (the username). But the other brackets should remain.

Comment: Please explain what is *first tag* and what is *text after it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^[^<]*<[^>]*>(.*)$/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

**Explanation:**

- **^** start of line
- **[^<]*** zero or more characters which are not < character
- **<** character
- **[^>]*** zero or more characters which are not > character
- **>** character
- **(.*)** intended capture group
- **$** end of line

Note that this is making certain assumptions about what exactly you want since it's not entirely clear to me.  It will capture everything, (including any additional tags), following the initial tag group.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have 2 problems here - first the processing and secondly echoing < and > which will be treated as html tags if you want these used as tags then second set of code

so

```
<?php
$string1 = "<@231312312312> foobar <asad> foobar";    
$string2 = substr($string1, strpos($string1, ">") + 1);  
echo htmlspecialchars($string2);
?>

<?php
$string1 = "<@231312312312> foobar <asad> foobar";    
$string2 = substr($string1, strpos($string1, ">") + 1);  
echo $string2;
?>
```